# No module named foo.settings Django Import Error

Tags: python, django, importerror

I'm gettings a Django import error after just cloning a repo for the first time, and I've looked at all previous questions and can't figure out what my problem is...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 12, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 302, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 99, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named foo.settings
```

But I have my settings.py file in the foo directory?

> > Project
> >
> > > app1
> > >
> > > app2
> > >
> > > foo
> > >
> > > > settings.py
> > > >
> > > > wsgi.py
> > > >
> > > > urls.py
> > >
> > > app3
> > >
> > > manage.py

I am really confused. Here is my manage.py

```
# !/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys


if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "foo.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` file in the foo directory?

Comment: Or is it that your settings folder is called `foo`, whereas the import in manage.py is asking for `hieta`?

Comment: @nimasmi whoops dodgy renaming.... that was just bad post edits.

Comment: Been there done that. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Python to recognise a directory as a module, it needs to contain a file named `__init__.py`. This file can be empty, or can contain module top-level code.

From the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages):

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages

Related SO Question: [What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)